# Не могу написать счетчик перестановок и сравнений для сортировок вставками

Tags: python, сортировка

Уже везде пробовал вставлять счетчики.  В сортировке вставками он считает проход каждого цикла, а нужны только перестановки, формулу для вычисления сравнений я знаю, нужны только перестановки.

```
import random

def BubbleSort(a):  # функция сортировки пузырьком
    count = 0  # счетчик перестановок
    for i in range(len(a), 0, -1):
        flag = True
        for j in range(1, i):
            if a[j - 1] > a[j]:
                c = a[j - 1]
                a[j - 1] = a[j]
                a[j] = c
                count += 1
                flag = False
        if flag:
            break
    print('Произведено сравнений', count * (count -1)/ 2)
    print ('Произведено перестановок: ', count)
    return a


def InsertionSort(a): # функция сортировки вставками
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        v = a[i]
        j = i
        count += 1
        while (a[j-1] > v) and (j > 0):
            a[j] = a[j-1]
            j = j - 1
            a[j] = v

    print('Произведено сравнений: ', count * (count - 1) / 2)
    print('Произведено перестановок: ', )
    return a

print('¬ведите тип массива(1- случайные данные, 2- перевернутый, 3- почти отсортированный)')
q = input()
print('¬ведите размерность массива')
b = input()
if q == str('1'):
    a = [0] * int(b)
    for i in range(int(b)):
        a[i] = int(random.randint(1, 100))
elif q == str('2'):
    a = list(range(int(b)))
    a.reverse()
elif q == str('3'):
    a = list(range(int(b)))
    a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))] = a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))]


print ('Сгенерированный массив: ', a)
print ('Результат сортировки пузырьком:', BubbleSort(a))
print ('Результат сортировки вставками:', InsertionSort(a))
```

Comment: Нельзя ль объяснить понятней, что нужно, в чем проблема и что не получается.

Answer (score 0):

У вас после выполнения функции `BubbleSort` список `a` отсортирован и поэтому функция `InsertionSort` ничего не переставляет.

```
import random

def BubbleSort(a):  # функция сортировки пузырьком
    count = 0  # счетчик перестановок
    for i in range(len(a), 0, -1):
        flag = True
        for j in range(1, i):
            if a[j - 1] > a[j]:
                c = a[j - 1]
                a[j - 1] = a[j]
                a[j] = c
                count += 1
                flag = False
        if flag:
            break
    print('Произведено сравнений (пузырьком):', count * (count -1)/ 2)
    print ('Произведено перестановок (пузырьком):', count)
    return a


def InsertionSort(a): # функция сортировки вставками
    count = pere = 0                                 # <---
    for i in range(len(a)):
        v = a[i]
        j = i
        count += 1
        while (a[j-1] > v) and (j > 0):
            a[j] = a[j-1]
            j = j - 1
            a[j] = v
            pere += 1                                # <---


    print('Произведено сравнений: ', count * (count - 1) / 2)
    print('Произведено перестановок: ', pere)
    return a

print('\nведите тип массива(1- случайные данные, 2- перевернутый, 3- почти отсортированный)')
q = input()
print('\nведите размерность массива')
b = input()
if q == str('1'):
    a = [0] * int(b)
    for i in range(int(b)):
        a[i] = int(random.randint(1, 100))
elif q == str('2'):
    a = list(range(int(b)))
    a.reverse()
elif q == str('3'):
    a = list(range(int(b)))
    a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))] = a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))]

a2 = a.copy()                                                 # <---

print ('Сгенерированный массив: ', a)
print ('Результат сортировки пузырьком:', BubbleSort(a))
print ('Результат сортировки вставками:', InsertionSort(a2))  # <---
```

---

```
ведите тип массива(1- случайные данные, 2- перевернутый, 3- почти отсортированный)
1

ведите размерность массива
5
Сгенерированный массив:  [82, 2, 44, 8, 86]
Произведено сравнений (пузырьком): 6.0
Произведено перестановок (пузырьком): 4
Результат сортировки пузырьком: [2, 8, 44, 82, 86]
Произведено сравнений:  10.0
Произведено перестановок:  4
Результат сортировки вставками: [2, 8, 44, 82, 86]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def insertion_sort(arr):
    shifts = 0
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        key = arr[i]
        j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and key < arr[j]:
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j]
            j -= 1
            shifts += 1
        arr[j + 1] = key
    return shifts

a = [6,5,4,3,1,2]
print('Insertion count:', insertion_sort(a))
print(a)
```